# How to fetch collection of subdocument using mongodb C# driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-.net-driver

I have following MongoDB document:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5fbfa0005c15aaf2eac69ba6"
  },
  "PostMedia": [
    {
      "FilePath": "http://localhost:8886/localhost44323/image/",
      "Filename": "img1.jpg",
      "Title": null,
      "Description": ""
    },
    {
      "FilePath": "http://localhost:8886/localhost44323/image/",
      "Filename": "img2.jpg",
      "Title": null,
      "Description": ""
    }
  ]
},
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5fbfa0485c15aaf2eac69ba7"
  },
  "PostMedia": [
    {
      "FilePath": "http://localhost:8886/localhost44323/image/",
      "Filename": "img3.jpg",
      "Title": null,
      "Description": ""
    },
    {
      "FilePath": "http://localhost:8886/localhost44323/image/",
      "Filename": "img4.jpg",
      "Title": null,
      "Description": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

and I want to fetch all `PostMedia` to single array using MongoDB C# driver.
Here is the expected result:

```
[
    {
      "FilePath": "http://localhost:8886/localhost44323/image/",
      "Filename": "img1.jpg",
      "Title": null,
      "Description": ""
    },
    {
      "FilePath": "http://localhost:8886/localhost44323/image/",
      "Filename": "img2.jpg",
      "Title": null,
      "Description": ""
    }, {
      "FilePath": "http://localhost:8886/localhost44323/image/",
      "Filename": "img3.jpg",
      "Title": null,
      "Description": ""
    },
    {
      "FilePath": "http://localhost:8886/localhost44323/image/",
      "Filename": "img4.jpg",
      "Title": null,
      "Description": ""
    }
  ]
```

I had tried to use group aggregation function but it returned an array of array.

[image]

Result I received:

```
PostMedia:[{
      "FilePath": "http://localhost:8886/localhost44323/image/",
      "Filename": "img1.jpg",
      "Title": null,
      "Description": ""
    },
    {
      "FilePath": "http://localhost:8886/localhost44323/image/",
      "Filename": "img2.jpg",
      "Title": null,
      "Description": ""
    }],[
     {
      "FilePath": "http://localhost:8886/localhost44323/image/",
      "Filename": "img3.jpg",
      "Title": null,
      "Description": ""
    },
    {
      "FilePath": "http://localhost:8886/localhost44323/image/",
      "Filename": "img4.jpg",
      "Title": null,
      "Description": ""
    }
  ]
```

C# code I have written so far is as follows:

```
  var group = new[]
                {
                new BsonDocument("$group",
                new BsonDocument
                {
                    { "_id", BsonNull.Value },
                    { "PostMedia", new BsonDocument("$push", "$PostMedia") }
                })
            };
                var result = collection.Aggregate<MediaList>(group).FirstOrDefault();
                return list;
            }
```

Is there any way to fetch subdocument by merging them is a single array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `$unwind` before `$group`,

- `$unwind` deconstruct `PostMedia` array
- `$replaceRoot` replace `PostMedia` object to root
- `$unset` remove `_id` field

```
  { $unwind: "$PostMedia" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      PostMedia: { $push: "$PostMedia" }
    }
  },
  { $unset: "_id" } // remove field
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/z7yub-MZrWJ)

**C#:**

```
new BsonArray
{
    new BsonDocument("$unwind", "$PostMedia"),
    new BsonDocument("$group", 
    new BsonDocument
        {
            { "_id", BsonNull.Value }, 
            { "PostMedia", 
    new BsonDocument("$push", "$PostMedia") }
        })
    new BsonDocument("$unset", "_id")
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to ignore _id

Comment: it requires to add `$unset` stage after $group stage, `{ $unset: "_id" }`

Comment: `{
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$PostMedia"
    }
  }` is throwing me error what is wrong here can you guid me

Comment: what is the error and where is throwing error?. i don't know c# if the error is from c#, but will try.

Comment: can you go through this snippet https://mongoplayground.net/p/w_hoDgvWmcq

Comment: I think mongodb is unable to pars array as object

Comment: do you need this objects in root from array?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227322/discussion-between-kiran-shahi-and-turivishal).